# Visual studio 2013 c++ lambda capture parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, visual-studio-2013

Currently Visual Studio 2013 update 2 does not support full C++11, one of those features is capturing parameter packs in a lambda. Is there an easy way to work around this or will I have to resort to ditching visual studio and using a compliant compiler such as mingw/g++?

The following code demonstrates a simple use case of what I had in mind:

```
template <typename ... Args>
std::thread init_threaded(SomeObject sample, Args && ... args)
{
  auto func = [=]()
  {
    sample->init(args...);
  };

  return std::thread(func);
}
```

This works great in the latest xcode (5.1.1) and recent versions of g++ (using 4.9.0) under linux however in visual studio 2013 update 2 it gives the error:

```
error C2536: 'init_threaded::<lambda_3a984affe0045c597607c0ec0a116b46>::init_threaded::<lambda_3a984affe0045c597607c0ec0a116b46>::<args_0>' : cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays
```

**Edit:**
This error seems to only happen when there are different types in the init function. The following example does not compile.

```
#include <thread>

struct foo
{
    void init(int arg1, std::string arg2) {}
};


template <typename ... Args>
std::thread init_threaded(foo *sample, Args && ... args)
{
    auto func = [=]()
    {
        sample->init(args...);
    };

    return std::thread(func);
}


int main()
{
    foo f;
    auto t = init_threaded(&f, 1, "two");
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: `std::thread` allows you to pass arguments in the constructor. `[=](Args... args_){ sample->init(args_...); }` and then `std::thread(func, std::forward<Args>(args)...)` should work.

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5dd29ee2b28fad9) compiles and runs on VS2013. And so does [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ea45f70c8dd4c37). Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the error?

Comment: I've updated with an SSCCE, I was shorting quite a few subsystems to get the example above, turns out the issue is when using different types, not sure why your int and long worked but int and string does not work.

Comment: figured it out. In the example above I'm passing "two" however if I pass std::string("two") it works. It looks like visual studio isn't converting const char* into std::string like all the other compilers, is visual studio correct here on the standard or should I fill a bug with microsoft?

Comment: I think microsoft is correct here. It would do what would be the easiest way of looking at data types. First all compilers try to do `const char*` and a default conversion only happens when you do something like `const std::string& arg2`. Can you try that instead?

Comment: @AbhiP: Hahaha, no, MSVC is definitly wrong here. The conversion should also happen for simple by-value parameters.

Comment: Does look like an MSVC bug. The parameter pack should be deduced as `(int, char const[4])` but the second type should decay to pointer when you pass to `string` constructor (or maybe even when you capture the args by value in the lambda, not sure which one). MSVC does compile the code if you change the lambda to capture by reference, but that may create lifetime issues. Explicitly creating the `string` or `static_cast<char const *>("two")` are probably the way to work around this.

Comment: I've now filled a bug here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/888992/visual-studio-2013-parameter-packs-and-lambda-capture-bug. This question is now closed.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comment this is a MSVC compiler bug and there is a work around. The bug ticket is [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/888992/visual-studio-2013-parameter-packs-and-lambda-capture-bug) in case anyone else runs into this and wants to know the status.

Comment: Unfortunately MS appear to have locked away all the old Connect issues.  Is there any discussion of this elsewhere?