# C++11 lambdas and parameter packs

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I'm having essentially the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029833/visual-studio-2013-c-lambda-capture-parameter-pack), however unfortunately the only posted answer there is now a dead link.

Specifically, using VS2013 Update 4, I'm trying to get the following code to compile, and it's not being cooperative:

```
template<typename T, typename... Params>
auto PostWeakTask(const boost::weak_ptr<IWorkQueue>& queue,
                  void (T::*member)(Params...),
                  const boost::weak_ptr<T>& weak)
    -> std::function<void (Params&&...)>
{
    return [queue, member, weak](Params&&... params)
    {
        if (auto qp = queue.lock())
        {
            qp->Post([weak, member, params]()
            {
                if (auto strong = weak.lock())
                {
                    ((*strong).*member)(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

(As written, the capture of `params` fails with `C3481: 'params': lambda capture variable not found`.  If I try using implicit capture with `=` instead, it says `C2065: 'params' : undeclared identifier`.  If I try `params...`, I get `C3521: 'params' is not a parameter pack`.)

The idea of course is to return a function that when called will post a member function with arbitrary parameters to a work queue that accepts `void()` tasks only, and to only keep weak references to the queue and task when not yet executed.

I don't think there's anything actually wrong in the code here, though.  I think I've found a workaround using `bind` instead of a lambda, but oddly it only seems to work with `std::function` and not `boost::function`.  (Using Boost 1.55.  I suspect this might be pre-rvalue-ref support?)

(On a side note, I originally tried to use `decltype([](Params&&...){})` as the return type, as this seems more natural.  But it crashes the compiler.)

---

The workaround is doing something a bit weird too.  Maybe I should ask this as a separate question as it mostly relates to the perfect-forwarding part instead, but:

```
template<typename T, typename... Params>
auto PostWeakTask(const boost::weak_ptr<IWorkQueue>& queue,
                  void (T::*member)(Params...),
                  const boost::weak_ptr<T>& weak)
    -> std::function<void (Params...)>
{
    struct WeakCaller
    {
        typedef void (T::*member_type)(Params...);
        typedef boost::weak_ptr<T> weak_type;

        WeakCaller(member_type member, const weak_type& weak)
            : m_member(member), m_weak(weak) {}

        void operator()(Params&&... params)
        {
            if (auto strong = m_weak.lock())
            {
                ((*strong).*m_member)(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
            }
        }

    private:
        member_type m_member;
        weak_type m_weak;
    };

    return [=](Params&&... params)
    {
        if (auto qp = queue.lock())
        {
            qp->Post(std::bind(WeakCaller(member, weak),
                     std::forward<Params>(params)...));
        }
    }
}
```

This seems like it should work, but when I try calling it (with a `void (tribool,tribool,const std::string&)` method) I get a binding error that a `tribool` parameter is not compatible with a `tribool&&` one.

(Specifically: `C2664: 'void WeakCaller<T,boost::logic::tribool,boost::logic::tribool,const std::string &>::operator ()(boost::logic::tribool &&,boost::logic::tribool &&,const std::string &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'boost::logic::tribool' to 'boost::logic::tribool &&'`.)

I thought part of the point of using rvalue references this way was that they were supposed to forward perfectly without needing multiple overloads?

I can make it compile by making `WeakCaller` have `void operator()(Params... params)` instead, but doesn't this defeat perfect forwarding?  (Oddly it seems ok with leaving the `&&` at the top-level lambda... and I'm not sure if the mismatch between the `std::function` signature and the lambda signature is ok.)

---

Just for reference, here is the final version I'm using now, after tweaking [Oktalist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35782030/43534):

```
namespace detail
{
    template<size_t... Ints> struct index_sequence
    {
        static size_t size() { return sizeof...(Ints); }
    };

    template<size_t Start, typename Indices, size_t End>
    struct make_index_sequence_impl;

    template<size_t Start, size_t... Indices, size_t End>
    struct make_index_sequence_impl<Start, index_sequence<Indices...>, End>
    {
        typedef typename make_index_sequence_impl<
            Start + 1, index_sequence<Indices..., Start>, End>::type type;
    };

    template<size_t End, size_t... Indices>
    struct make_index_sequence_impl<End, index_sequence<Indices...>, End>
    {
        typedef index_sequence<Indices...> type;
    };

    template <size_t N>
    using make_index_sequence = typename
        make_index_sequence_impl<0, index_sequence<>, N>::type;

    template<typename... Ts>
    using index_sequence_for = make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>;

    template<typename... Ts>
    struct MoveTupleWrapper
    {
        MoveTupleWrapper(std::tuple<Ts...>&& tuple)
            : m_tuple(std::move(tuple)) {}
        MoveTupleWrapper(const MoveTupleWrapper& other)
            : m_tuple(std::move(other.m_tuple)) {}
        MoveTupleWrapper& operator=(const MoveTupleWrapper& other)
            { m_tuple = std::move(other.m_tuple); }

        template<typename T, typename... Params>
        void apply(void (T::*member)(Params...), T& object) const
        {
            applyHelper(member, object, index_sequence_for<Ts...>());
        }

        template<typename T, typename... Params, size_t... Is>
        void applyHelper(void (T::*member)(Params...), T& object,
                         index_sequence<Is...>) const
        {
            (object.*member)(std::move(std::get<Is>(m_tuple))...);
        }

    private:
        mutable std::tuple<Ts...> m_tuple;
    };

    template<typename... Ts>
    auto MoveTuple(Ts&&... objects)
        -> MoveTupleWrapper<std::decay_t<Ts>...>
    {
        return std::make_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(objects)...);
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Params>
    struct WeakTaskPoster
    {
        WeakTaskPoster(const boost::weak_ptr<IWorkQueue>& queue,
                       void (T::*member)(Params...),
                       const boost::weak_ptr<T>& weak) :
            m_queue(queue),
            m_member(member),
            m_weak(weak)
        {}

        template<typename... XParams>
        void operator()(XParams&&... params) const
        {
            if (auto qp = m_queue.lock())
            {
                auto weak = m_weak;
                auto member = m_member;
                auto tuple = MoveTuple(std::forward<XParams>(params)...);
                qp->Post([weak, member, tuple]()
                {
                    if (auto strong = weak.lock())
                    {
                        tuple.apply(member, *strong);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    private:
        boost::weak_ptr<IWorkQueue> m_queue;
        void (T::*m_member)(Params...);
        boost::weak_ptr<T> m_weak;
    };
}

template<typename T, typename... Params>
auto PostWeakTask(const boost::weak_ptr<IWorkQueue>& queue,
                  void (T::*member)(Params...),
                  const boost::weak_ptr<T>& weak)
    -> detail::WeakTaskPoster<T, Params...>
{
    return { queue, member, weak };
}
```

I guess it's still not truly universal since it doesn't work with lvalue references, but since those are dangerous in a delayed callback context anyway this is not that important.

(Although, if you're really desperate to pass lvalue references around, it appears to work if you call with `std::ref(x)` and receive as `std::reference_wrapper<T>` (or `const&` or `&&`).  There's probably some additional magic that could make this transparent, but I don't really need it so I haven't investigated.)

Comment: Hmm, an occurrence of a pack without an expansion?

Comment: @Columbo I'm not sure which part you're referring to.

Comment: `[weak, params]() {…}`

Comment: @Columbo Have a look at the text just below that.  I tried several variations, including an attempted expansion.

Comment: `member` is not captured either.

Comment: The attempted expansion would have been the correct way, so use that as an example.  Either way, your compiler is crap, so you'll have to stick with a workaround for now.

Comment: @Jarod42 True, that was a typo -- it was correct in the original code.  I've corrected that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought part of the point of using rvalue references this way was that they were supposed to forward perfectly without needing multiple overloads?

No, rvalue references and forwarding references are two different things. They both involve `&&` but they behave differently. Forwarding references occur only in the presence of template argument deduction (or `auto` type deduction, which uses the same rules).

This is a forwarding reference:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& v);
```

Template argument deduction will let `T` be any type; if `T` is an lvalue reference then `v` is an lvalue reference, otherwise `v` is an rvalue reference, due to reference collapsing.

This is NOT a forwarding reference:

```
void foo(int&& v);
```

There is no template argument deduction here, so `v` is a plain rvalue reference to `int`, it can bind only to rvalues.

This is also NOT a forwarding reference:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    void bar(T&& v);
};
```

Again because there is no template argument deduction. The function `Foo<int>::bar` is not a template, it is a plain function taking a plain rvalue reference parameter which can bind only to rvalues. The function `Foo<int&>::bar` is a plain function taking a plain lvalue reference parameter which can bind only to lvalues.

> On a side note, I originally tried to use `decltype([](Params&&...){})` as the return type, as this seems more natural.

That would never work. Every lambda expression denotes a unique type, so `decltype([]{})` and `decltype([]{})` are two different, unrelated types.

Here is a possible solution. The only C++14 feature used is `std::index_sequence`, for which you can Google a C++11 implementation.

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct MoveTupleWrapper
{
    MoveTupleWrapper(std::tuple<Ts...>&& tuple) : m_tuple(tuple) {}
    MoveTupleWrapper(MoveTupleWrapper& other) : m_tuple(std::move(other.m_tuple)) {}
    MoveTupleWrapper& operator=(MoveTupleWrapper& other) { m_tuple = std::move(other.m_tuple); }
    std::tuple<Ts...> m_tuple;

    template<typename T, typename... Params>
    void apply(void (T::*member)(Params...), T& object)
    {
        applyHelper(member, object, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>);
    }
    template<typename T, typename... Params, size_t... Is>
    void applyHelper(void (T::*member)(Params...), T& object, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        (object.*member)(std::move(std::get<Is>(m_tuple))...);
    }
};

template<typename... Ts>
auto MoveTuple(Ts&&... objects)
    -> MoveTupleWrapper<std::decay_t<Ts>...>
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(objects)...);
}

template<typename T, typename... Params>
struct WeakTaskPoster
{
    WeakTaskPoster(const boost::weak_ptr<IWorkQueue>& queue,
                   void (T::*member)(Params...),
                   const boost::weak_ptr<T>& weak) :
        m_queue(queue),
        m_member(member),
        m_weak(weak)
    {}
    boost::weak_ptr<IWorkQueue> m_queue;
    void (T::*m_member)(Params...);
    boost::weak_ptr<T> m_weak;

    template<typename... XParams>
    void operator()(XParams&&... params) const
    {
        if (auto qp = m_queue.lock())
        {
            auto weak = m_weak;
            auto member = m_member;
            auto tuple = MoveTuple(std::forward<XParams>(params)...);
            qp->Post([weak, member, tuple]() mutable
            {
                if (auto strong = weak.lock())
                {
                    tuple.apply(member, *strong);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

template<typename T, typename... Params>
auto PostWeakTask(const boost::weak_ptr<IWorkQueue>& queue,
                  void (T::*member)(Params...),
                  const boost::weak_ptr<T>& weak)
    -> WeakTaskPoster<T, Params...>
{
    return { queue, member, weak };
}
```

Note that `WeakTaskPoster::operator()` is a template, so we obtain perfect forwarding. The C++14 way to do that would've been a generic lambda. Then there is this `MoveTuple` thing. That's a wrapper around a `std::tuple` which simply implements copy in terms of move, so we can work around the lack of C++14 lambda capture-by-move. It also implements exactly the subset of `std::apply` that is necessary.

It's very similar to Yakk's answer, except that the tuple of parameters is moved instead of copied into the lambda's capture set.

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful.  Although it seems a bit weird to implement copy constructors as move constructors -- wasn't that the thing everyone hated about `auto_ptr`?  Also, I tried using [this implementation](http://pdimov.com/cpp2/simple_cxx11_metaprogramming.html) of `std::index_sequence`, but it causes an internal compiler error.  Do you know of a better one?

Comment: Ok, I found [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245856/how-to-implement-a-variadic-tuple-map-operation) that seems to work.

I had to make a couple of tweaks to the above (mostly adding `const` in a few places), and it does compile and work for copyable types.  However it's having the same problem as the `bind`-based one for move-only types.

I'll add the move-only test case that I'm using to the question, since it's easier to format it there.  Maybe I'm doing something dumb?

Comment: Never mind, I worked it out.  After adding the `const` (so that `MoveTupleWrapper` actually had a copy constructor, not merely a reference constructor), the `std::move` still ended up invoking the tuple's copy constructor, because `const tuple&&` can be passed to `const tuple&` and can't be passed to `tuple&&`.  (It would be nice if this had generated a compiler warning so this was more obvious.)  Making the `m_tuple` member `mutable` fixed this, so I now have a fully working solution, thanks!

Comment: I noticed the similarity to `autoptr`. You are of course correct that it's a bit evil, but this is what VS2013 imposes on us. I've made an edit, adding `mutable` to the lambda (not the tuple) which is probably the better fix. The lack of `const` in the copy ctor and operator is valid and intended. But adding `const` and `mutable` as you have done will also work, it slightly obscures the fact that the copy ctor and operator will modify `other` (by moving from its `m_tuple` member).

Comment: Omitting the `const` from the copy constructor causes compiler error `MoveTupleWrapper<>' : no copy constructor available or copy constructor is declared 'explicit'`, even with `mutable` on the lambda.  I added my current version of the above to the end of the question.  It's a little ugly that it moves from a const parameter, but that's just an internal detail and it does compile and passes tests.  (Though not for lvalue-refs, but that's not surprising.)

Comment: Actually, it can be persuaded to work with lvalue refs too, although it's a bit clunky.  I'm not really expecting to need those though, so it's fine.

Comment: A non-const lvalue reference would usually denote an output parameter. The caller might expect `member` to modify the argument through the reference, but as currently written, it would only be modifying the captured copy. You'd want to wrap it with `std::ref`, and then you'd want to avoid the default behaviour of `std::make_tuple` which is to unwrap the reference wrapper, and you'd need to be sure that the lifetime of the lambda would not exceed the lifetime of the argument.

Comment: See the addition to the question (added prior to my comment above).  It appears that `std::ref` doesn't get unwrapped automatically anyway (though perhaps this is a VS2013 defect; I haven't tested on any other compilers).

Comment: I could be wrong about having to avoid the unwrap. The resulting tuple can't be copy assigned but can be copy constructed which is probably sufficient. But as I have written it, it would _move from_ the original lvalue argument which is probably not what you would want.

Comment: I assume you mean if not using `std::ref`?  When using `std::ref` it will try to move from the `reference_wrapper`, which will decay to a copy, and everything after that just works.  (I tested it, although admittedly only with a `reference_wrapper<int>` so it's possible I missed some side effect.)

Comment: Although there does seem to be something odd going on.  When I used `std::ref` I definitely received a `reference_wrapper<T>` in the wrapped callback.  But you're right that `make_tuple` (even in VS2013) does pass the parameter types through a reference-unwrapper metafunction.  So I'm not sure why it survived that.

Answer (score 1):

Make things work is my goal.

I'll attack this:

```
qp->Post([weak, member, params]()
{
  if (auto strong = weak.lock()) {
    ((*strong).*member)(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
  }
});
```

First, let us get `params` into the lambda.

```
auto tParams = std::make_tuple( std::forward<Params>(params)... );
qp->Post([weak, member, tParams]()
{
  if (auto strong = weak.lock()) {
    ((*strong).*member)(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
  }
});
```

however, you'll note that now the body doesn't compile!

We are, however, closer.

```
template<class T, class M>
struct member_invoke_t;
template<class T, class R, class...Args>
struct member_invoke_t<T*, R(::*)(Args...)> {
  T* t;
  R(::*m)(Args...);
  template<class...Ts>
  R operator()(Ts&&...ts)const{
    return (t->*m)(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }
};
template<class T, class M>
member_invoke_t<T*, M*> member_invoke(T* t, M*m) {
  return {t, m};
};
```

then we only have to write `std::apply`

```
qp->Post([weak, member, tParams]()mutable
{
  if (auto strong = weak.lock())
    std::apply( member_invoke(strong.get(), member), std::move(tParams) );
}
```

which should be doable.  (The above code assumes that the lambda passed to `Post` will only be invoked once by the way -- hence the `move` and the `mutable`).

`std::apply` has a possible C++14 implementation [over here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/apply).  Converting to C++11 requires writing `index_sequence` and replacing the `decltype(auto)` with an explicit `->decltype(expression)` I think.  In any case, that is a sub-problem I'll skip here.

Comment: Considering the target compiler is VS2013, which is barely C++11 and not C++14, I'm not sure this is all that useful.  Definitely interesting, however.  I'm not sure it's all that different in practice from the workaround I posted myself, though.

Answer (score 0):

[Yakk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35761260/43534) did inspire me a bit to make a slight alteration to the workaround posted above:

```
template<typename T, typename... Params>
struct WeakCaller
{
    typedef void (T::*member_type)(Params...);
    typedef boost::weak_ptr<T> weak_type;

    WeakCaller(member_type member, const weak_type& weak)
        : m_member(member), m_weak(weak) {}

    template<typename... Args>
    void operator()(Args&&... params)
    {
        if (auto strong = m_weak.lock())
        {
            ((*strong).*m_member)(std::forward<Args>(params)...);
        }
    }

private:
    member_type m_member;
    weak_type m_weak;
};

template<typename T, typename... Params>
auto PostWeakTask(const boost::weak_ptr<IWorkQueue>& queue,
                  void (T::*member)(Params...),
                  const boost::weak_ptr<T>& weak)
    -> std::function<void (Params...)>
{
    return [=](Params&&... params)
    {
        if (auto qp = queue.lock())
        {
            qp->Post(std::bind(WeakCaller<T, Params...>(member, weak),
                     std::forward<Params>(params)...));
        }
    }
}
```

This appears to compile and work as expected, although I haven't tested it with move-only types yet (I suspect they will be problematic due to the use of `bind` and `function`).  I'm not really sure why re-templating the operator was needed, but it seems to bypass the compiler errors I was having with `&&` params.

I'm also still not sure whether the return type of `PostWeakTask` should be `std::function<void(Params...)>` or `std::function<void(Params&&...)>`; it seems to compile ok both ways.

Comment: The templated `operator()` is needed to obtain perfect forwarding. Without it, your rvalue references are just rvalue references, not forwarding references.

Comment: The same goes for `[=](Params&&... params)` and `std::function<void(Params&&...)>`, just adding `&&` to the parameter types of the `member` function doesn't magically create forwarding references.

Comment: @Oktalist So are you saying that this version still has problems, or that it's fine as is?

Comment: FWIW, further testing shows that using `Params...` (no `&&` or `std::forward`) on the lambda is sufficient for copyable types, but neither version works for move-only types.  Which is disappointing but not surprising.  I'm ok with things as they are but would appreciate a moveable version if someone were so inclined.

Comment: For VS2013 it's difficult. Yakk's answer should work.